# Swapping table td on drag

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop, swap

I am trying to swap two TD elements in table on Drag&Drop. I found this plugin [Swappable](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_home.html) and it works in some way. But when I drag some element the cursor change position to some specific value. I do not want changing cursor position. But when I rework this plugin it stops work.

Does anyone have experience with it or know about any other plugin?

Thanks,
Zbynek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I use the [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).  It does pretty much want you want. You can use it in a table too.

Then I do my stuff (including ajax updates) in a function setted in the [receive event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive)

Comment: jquery sortable do sorting but i want to swap the values.suppose if their are values 1,2,3,4  then swapping 1 and 4 make it 4,2,3,1 but when i use sorting it becomes 4,1,2,3.I want to achieve swapping.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the JQuery Sortable() option?
See http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: Yes I tried it and I specify that DIV from TD is the item to sort. But it start making crazy things. It put more DIVs into one TD. But I do not want this. I want spaw two TDs content.